# How to create table in one server as like a table from another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am connecting two databases that are in 2 different servers like

```
$connection_from = new mysqli($databasehost_from,$databaseusername_from,$databasepassword_from,$databasename_from);
$connection_to = new mysqli($databasehost_to,$databaseusername_to,$databasepassword_to,$databasename_to);
```

And now I want to create table `table2` and insert same data in 2nd host database as it is already present in 1st host database.Can anyone please suggest me to do it in a right way.I have tried like

```
CREATE TABLE connection_to.table2 AS SELECT * FROM connection_from.table1
```

but but I didn't found that the table was created even.

Comment: Even if you can use the [federated storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-storage-engine.html), you've got to issue two `CREATE TABLE` statements for the new table. But you would be able to get your data into the second host via `INSERT INTO ... SELECT.`

Comment: may be can pull data from the 1st connection and store that in second one by Insert query

Comment: If the table stays the same (only needs to be created once), use phpMyAdmin to export the table's `CREATE` statement, then use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` syntax. Otherwise, you can try replication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to replicate databases, don't use PHP.  MySQL has replication built into it.  Use that.  It performs diffs rather than full transfers, so it works a lot faster.

If you can't or don't want to use replication, you should look at using pipes on the command line.  If the database grows to a large enough size, you will have issues forming a transfer using PHP since the variables size will exceed the PHP variable size limit.  You can use the `system` method on the command line and perform a read from one database and pipe that into a write on another database.  This assumes you are using a Linux system.  If you are on Windows... move to Linux.

If you are performing this action regularly, you might look at just writing a script and setting up a cron task to handle it.